# Which PHP interface allows objects' properties to be accessible with array notation?

Tags: php, arrays, spl, arrayobject

Which PHP SPL interface allows objects to do this:

```
$object->month = 'january';
echo $object['month']; // january

$record['day'] = 'saturday';
echo $record->day; // saturday
```

e.g. such as in libraries like Doctrine (Doctrine_Record)

how do I implement this? I've tried using ArrayObject, but they don't behave as I thought they would.

i.e.

```
$object = new ArrayObject();
$object['a'] = 'test';
$object['a'] == $object->a; // false
```

**EDIT:**

I tried a barebone implementation that I called Arrayable.

```
class Arrayable implements ArrayAccess
{
    protected $container = array();

    # implement ArrayAccess methods to allow array notation 
    # $object = new Arrayable();
    # $object['value'] = 'some data';

    function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->container[$offset];
    }

    function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->container[$offset] = $value;
    }

    function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    # now, force $object->value to map to $object['value'] 
    # using magic methods

    function __set($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->offsetSet($offset, $value);
    }

    function __get($offset)
    {
        return $this->offsetGet($offset); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)

See the [sourcecode for Doctrine_Record](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/ormold/1.2/class-Doctrine_Record.html)

```
abstract class Doctrine_Record 
    extends Doctrine_Record_Abstract 
    implements Countable, IteratorAggregate, Serializable
```

and [Doctrine_Record_Abstract](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/ormold/1.2/class-Doctrine_Record_Abstract.html)

```
abstract class Doctrine_Record_Abstract extends Doctrine_Access
```

and finally [Doctrine_Access](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/ormold/1.2/class-Doctrine_Access.html)

```
abstract class Doctrine_Access 
    extends Doctrine_Locator_Injectable 
    implements ArrayAccess
```

From DocBlock

> Provides array access and property overload interface for Doctrine subclasses

---

An object implementing ArrayAccess has to have these methods

```
abstract public boolean offsetExists  ( mixed $offset  );
abstract public mixed offsetGet ( mixed $offset );
abstract public void offsetSet ( mixed $offset , mixed $value );
abstract public void offsetUnset ( mixed $offset );
```

There is a basic usage example in the PHP manual (linked above)

Answer (score 3):

You are using two different things here:

The ArrayAccess interface for `$a[key]` and
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php for `$a->key`

What happens is

`$a[key]` will call `$a->offsetGet(key)` (inherited from ArrayAccess) and `$a->key` will call `$a->__get(key)` or `$a->__set(key, val)` (in contexts like `$a->key = val`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can cast object and arrays..

```
$object = (object)array('name'=>'aviv');
echo $object->name; // prints aviv
```

And vise versa ..

```
$array= (array)$object;
echo $array['name']; // prints aviv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own class
e.g.

```
class PropertyTest {
 $month;
}
```

then in code use

```
$object = new PropertyTest;
$object->month = "January";
echo $obejct->month;
```

Comment: The OP wants to know how to access the object with array notation, e.g. `$object['month']` in addition to `$object->month`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the question using your example code with a minor addition:

```
<?php
$object = new ArrayObject([], ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);

$object['a'] = 'test';
var_dump($object['a'] == $object->a); // expected: bool(true)

$object->month = 'january';
echo $object['month'];               // expected: january

$object['day'] = 'saturday';
echo $object->day;                   // expected: saturday
```

**Demo**: https://3v4l.org/Nd5NW

---

**`ArrayObject`** accepts a 2nd constructor argument, which is either

- **ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST**
  Properties of the object have their normal functionality when accessed as list (var_dump, foreach, etc.).
- **ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS**
  Entries can be accessed as properties (read and write).

**Referencing**: http://php.net/manual/de/class.arrayobject.php